# Refactoring large case statement, externs, static locals

Tags: c++, extern

I'm trying to do some refactoring and wish to figure out the best path forward.

I have

```
  myonce{
    static int i //for operation 1
    switch(commandid) {
       case 1:  operation 1
                i = 1;
       ...
```

where myonce is a function that is called in a loop.  This is not my code, I'm trying to make it better.  Operation 1 (or each case) is a series of commands, and I want to put them in their own translation units (one function per file).

Since myonce runs in a loop, the original author has many static variables that he uses to keep state, some of these state sets are used across multiple operations.  Note that these are not static file scope, they are static block scope.

To keep things simple, as a proof of concept, I want to know if the following is possible.
Consider 1 operation with 1 set of static vars.

main.cpp

```
myonce {
   static int i //for op 1
   switch(commandid) {
       case 1:  operation1();
```

operation1.cpp

```
extern int i;
void operation1() {
   i = 1;
}
```

In the case of multiple operations using the same sets of state, I would make a header to declare them all extern.

Currently compilation of this file is counted in minutes, and my first goal is to break it up into smaller compilation units so that the author can work more freely.  this refactoring will take a long time, but I mention this as an explanation of my motivation of this approach.

I understand that a static file scope variable is not accessible to other translation units (extern in other files), so I wish to distinguish that this is not the case I'm handling.  What I don't know at the moment, is where I should declare operation1() to main, should it be

```
static int i
extern void operation1();
```

So that int is declared as visible to the function?

I would appreciate any pointers in this regard.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess after research, my question boils down to, do static function variables have external linkage, and the answer is no.  And not because they are declared static, its because they have the same scope as automatic variables.  If someone can confirm this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the state variables into a struct. Pass this struct to each function.

Example.

```
// foo.h
struct TheState
{
    int x;
    char *y;
    // ...
};

void func1(TheState &);
void func2(TheState &);

// main.cc
#include "foo.h"

void main_loop()
{
     TheState the_state;  // initialize this however you want

     for (;;)
     {
          if ( blah) func1(the_state);
          else func2(the_state);
     }
}

// func1.cc
#include "foo.h"

void func1(TheState &the_state)
{
     ++the_state.x;
}
```

Comment: This approach seems to be the one I'll need to take first.  Peter Schneider's answer is also good, mentioned similar things.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. `static` objects aren't visible in other source files, ever.

How large is your `switch` anyway? And what is the reason for modifying it?

Perhaps the original programmer had good reasons for the local, static variables? You say it is called in a loop, and some of the static variables are used to keep state from one iteration to the next, shared among branches of the switch. It is certainly a weird way to structure the code. I can think of doing something like this to run some sort of finite automaton, but in that case I'd write the automaton  as a string of snippets of code for each state, and transfer among them by straight `goto`s. I'd make *certain* somewhere very near there is a description of the automaton in a more readable form.

But I might be totally off-base. Can you share a bit more about what this code does?

Comment: The "good" reason he had is only that he is trying to fit his code inside someone else's framework.  The framework has initialization code he wanted to reuse, and the interface class declares a once function that is called every cycle.  He's ended up writing his own interpreter for commands, the switch being the operation each command should perform.  There is no good reason for the design, other than that he's had to do this to fit it in an existing framework.  At some point, I would strip out the framework's initialization code and go from there, but for now I'm looking to reduce this file.

Comment: The code tests hardware.  Or rather, writes and reads from a struct that is memory mapped to an fpga in charge of controlling hardware.  this big switch has all the logic for each command.  He has to use static block variables to maintain state through the loop.  He's decided to do this instead of put them as private members of the interface class he's using.  The file has grown to be very large.

Answer (score 1):

First, switches often are avoidable by creating better data structures with their functions (e.g. classes with a virtual member function `command` whose implementations do the right thing).

On a less ambitious level you could just pass pointers to the statics which are needed in that particular case to the function so that it can read and modify the state of those variables.

Depending on what the functions do, one could also pass state information as value parameters (copies), let the function do their work depending on that state, receive the results and THEN change global state in the main switch according to the result. The state change then is clearly visible (i.e. no side effects in the functions) and the noisy distracting details are banned to another file.

If each case tends to use many of the static variables then you could put them all in a struct; that change should be doable with a text editor (replace variable name x with mystruct.x etc.). Then each function just gets a pointer to that struct. EDIT: As I said in a comment: Perhaps the commands naturally form groups which are concerned with only parts of the state (e.g. there are commands which only read, others which only write data etc.). Then the global state could be split in corresponding groups of data. Each function only gets to see the data group which concerns it, which limits potential side effects.

But generally spoken the function as it is now seems badly designed/grown over time; working on a large set of static variables means having "side effects" in the code all over -- it's not easy to see what any given portion of code does and how it interacts with others. The information flow is not explicit. Analyzing clusters of data which belong together, organizing them in classes and separating them in files would be one task here, even without any virtual member functions.

As to your last question: The "case functions" you create (`operation1();` etc.) need only be known in the file which call them. If they are in one or several separate files you should create a header containing the prototypes.

Comment: I haven't ruled out the less ambitious method you describe.  I can't figure out the "right" architecture for this code yet, but right now my immediate need is to improve compilation time by allowing the author to add new commands in a way that minimizes recompilation.

Comment: About my last question, from what I've read about scope, I was trying to figure out what behavior would make a block variable visible to a translation unit as if it were a global.  So the c file with just the function would have externs for those variables, but do I need to do anything special to declare it s.t. the block variable declaration is in the proper scope when I go to call the function?

Comment: I think the solution von Matt McNabb and me, namely to bundle the variables holding state in a structure, is appropriate here. Then you just pass a pointer or reference to that structure to each "case" function. That kind of state holder is not uncommon. It would be nicer if that state could be split up, e.g. state of the input, state of processing, state of output or such. Then functions concerned only with reading stuff wouldn't need the output state (and couldn't change it inadvertently).

Comment: As to "what behavior would make a block variable visible to a translation unit as if it were a global": Doesn't work. Do not declare variables with the same name static in two files: Those would be different variables. Variables need to be global in order to span translation units (but doesn't have to be _known_ everywhere -- it's sufficient to declare them in those files where they are accessed). Globals are best avoided. Much better would be to pass parameters (possibly pointers or references) to functions defined in those other files.

Comment: After all this, I still don't have a clear grasp of all the scoping rules.  I'm going to put that approach down for now.  I appreciate your answer and your follow up comments.

Comment: While the details of scope are tricky the general idea is simple. There are basically three different lifetimes for objects: 1. Objects which live (roughly) from prog start to the end. True for globals which are declared "extern" in headers, and for objects on file scope declared static, and for static class members. 2. Objects which live from their explicit creation through new() to their (usually explicit) death through delete(). 3. Local objects inside a code block, perhaps a function, declared the normal way. They live from their definition to the end of the block they were declared in.

Comment: And static block/funciton variables, who aren't static class members, also have program lifetime, but what is their visibility?

Comment: I guess, specifically, if there is a file scope variable, static or otherwise, it is visible to functions defined later in the file.  I guess looking back, it doesn't make sense that variables declared inside functions would be visible to other sub functions called within, static or not.

Comment: Yes, all declared things (functions, variables) are only visible after their declaration, e.g. `extern int i;`. That's why headers (which contain declarations) are usually on top of the file. With such a declaration `i` would often be _defined_ (allocated and initialized) in a different file. A file which doesn't contain a declaration of `i` couldn't access it, although it is "there", kindof. File static variables are, as you say, also visible only after their declaration (which usually is also their definition).